# mysql docker container not getting started ,mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm

i've created a docker compose file to run the mysql docker container and using the database scripts initializing the database.

While starting the container i am getting the below error.

```
account-service-db_1  | Initializing database
account-service-db_1  | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T16:58:35.265463Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T16:58:35.265550Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) initializing of server in progress as process 15
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T16:58:35.268464Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010460] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T16:58:35.268472Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T16:58:35.269284Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T16:58:35.270510Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
docker-swarm-account-service-mysql-demo_account-service-db_1 exited with code 1
```

After research many people suggested to add user: "1000:50" in compose file will solve the issue .but after adding also i am getting the same error.

please find the my docker-compose file below

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 account-service-db:
    user: "1000:50"
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=account-service
      - MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpassword
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysqlpassword
    volumes:
      - "/Users/admin/dockerfiles/docker-swarm-account-service-mysql-demo/scripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
      - "/Users/admin/dockerfiles/docker-swarm-account-service-mysql-demo/account:/var/lib/mysql" 
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

    deploy:
     replicas: 1
     placement:
      constraints:
       - node.labels.mysql.node == true
     restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
      delay: 10s
      #max-attempts: 3
```

i am executing the above scenario in mac machine. Please help me why its behaving like this after giving all necessary permissions to volume and scripts folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your `account` folder. It might already be in use or corrupted. Create a new folder and test.

Remove double quotes from environment values in compose file.

If the folder on host that is being mounted does not have the required write permissions:

1. ssh to your host/node
2. `chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/account/folder`

Comment: i have changed but still same issue

Comment: account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T18:04:48.474871Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T18:04:49.598050Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 22 in a file operation.
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T18:04:49.598066Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 22 means 'Invalid argument'
account-service-db_1  | 2019-05-11T18:04:49.598075Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./undo_001: 'aio write' returned OS error 122. Cannot continue operati

Comment: in environment just keep 2: MYSQL_DATABASE=account-service and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysqlpassword....and try

Comment: try removing user field in docker-compose file and keep 2 envs as in above comment

Comment: yaa i am able to create , even i have seen some files created by docker container under account folder

Comment: is it possible for you to replicate in your machine with same configuration?

Comment: the new error that you have shared...i have updated the answer to solve that..please see..it should hopefully solve the issue

Comment: added still getting same error, can you share your compose file

Comment: with out this statement   - "/Users/admin/dockerfiles/docker-swarm-account-service-mysql-demo/account:/var/lib/mysql" i am able to launch the container.

Comment: What is your docker version

Comment: Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: Are you using docker for Mac. Switch back to Linux containers..this was the issue

Comment: finally its working now ,not sure what is the issue. i have deleted the account folder and rebooted mac ,now its working , not sure what is the cause

Comment: no i haven't switched , how to switch linux containers in mac machine

Comment: i did one more step as well    - "/Users/admin/dockerfiles/docker-swarm-account-service-mysql-demo/account:/var/lib/mysql" . i have removed the double quotes i and then started container.

Comment: Cool that I had asked to do yesterday I guess

Comment: Updating the answer.. might help others

Comment: Welcome ! Team effort

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer as I did ask you to try different folder and removing quotes

Comment: to solve th "[InnoDB] File ./undo_001: 'aio write' returned OS error 122. " problem,

add this command to your docker-compose.yml 

command: "--innodb_use_native_aio=0"

hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The same happened with me, to resolve the problem fast i did:

```
sail down -v
```

If you aren't using sail, you can do:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

This command will delete your container and your container's volumes, your database for example, will be all deleted, but for those who are in the dev mode and just wanna do the container work, this will help.

Then start the docker at your project:

```
 sail up -d
```

or

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: weird. but this one works for me, thanks